# CSS won’t link to pages other than index.html

Tags: html, css

Okay! I’m sure I’ve done something really stupid but I’m getting frustrated and thought I’d ask y’all for some help.  SO.

My file structure is like this:

Root file containing **index.html, /css/, /pages/, and /images/**.

I am working from /pages/bulletin.html and I have linked to an image via “../images/image.jpg”  and this works just fine.

For some stupid reason, I am unable to link to my css from these other pages.  Index.html links great and has had no issues but for some reason “**../css/css.css**” will not appear on any of the pages within **/pages/**.

I hope I just explained that okay, I just can’t tell what I’m doing wrong here?

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us, how you have linked stylesheet on html. Is it like `<link href="css/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: It’s <link href=“../css/css.css” type=“text/css” rel=“stylesheet” />

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **/pages/**,   you need `../../css/css`.css to access the file.

Better solution is to make it relative from the base, like

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You can link the same css file from it's root directory.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do show how you linked your css. But for a starter: Check if you're not linking as `..\css\css.css`, don't be too sure, check again. And as a means of debugging try linking via *local disk* path. Check for spaces, special characters. Who knows you might have mistyped in `link` element.

Answer (score 0):

As your `.html` file is placed in same directory where `css` folder is, you do not have to give `../`. If you that the control will search for css file one step back from your current directory, so it will be outside the main directory & you will not able to link css.
You can check this:

```
<link href="css/css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If your `.html` file is inside a folder inside main directory, then only you have to put `../` on link.